# aspnet_regiis -i fails with error

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, tfs

The latest version .Net 4.6 was installed on my PC.  I'm trying to run aspnet_regiis -i, but it keeps failing with a mysterious error:

> Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
>   Setup has detected some errors during the operation. For details, please read th
>   e setup log file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ASPNETSetup_00013.log.

When I look in ASPNETSetup_00013.log I see a line like the following.

> 2015-11-18 10:41:58           Starting    Creating directory:
>   C:\Workspace\site\aspnet_client 2015-11-18 10:41:58           Failure     Creating
>   directory: C:\Workspace\site\aspnet_client: CreateDirectoryInternal
>   failed with HRESULT

Any idea what this is?   I'm running aspnet_regiis -i as admin & there is no directory there.  There used to be.  It used to be mapped to a TFS project, but I checked the mappings & I don't see that there now.  Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I found out where aspnet_regiis was picking up the "C:\Workspace\site " path from.  It was a site in IIS that was pointing to an invalid directory.  I deleted that site & aspnet_regiis worked.